# socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, openssl, tcpserver, socketserver

I am trying to get a prototype ready and am having trouble getting a connection. I'm using OpenSSL for both the client and the server.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import SocketServer
import json
from OpenSSL import SSL
import os
import socket

TERMINATION_STRING = "Done"

CERTIFICATE_PATH = os.getcwd() + '/CA/certs/01.pem'
KEY_PATH = os.getcwd() + '/CA/private/key.pem'

class SSLThreadingTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer):
    def __init__(self, address, handler):
        SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer.__init__(self, address, handler)

        ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)

        #ctx.use_privatekey_file(KEY_PATH)
        #ctx.use_certificate_file(CERTIFICATE_PATH)
        self.socket = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(self.address_family, self.socket_type))

        print "Serving:", address[0], "on port:", address[1]



class MemberUpdateHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def setup(self):
        print self.client_address, "connected"

    def handle(self):
        data = ""
        while True:
            data += self.request.recv(1024).encode('utf-8').strip
            if data[-4:] == "Done":
                print "Done"
                break

            dataStrings = data.split(' ')
            for item in dataStrings:
                print item
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ADDRESS = 'localhost'
    PORT = 42424
    HOST = (ADDRESS, PORT)

    s = SSLThreadingTCPServer(HOST, MemberUpdateHandler)
    s.serve_forever()
```

And the client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from OpenSSL import SSL
import socket
import os

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 42424
ADDRESS = (HOST, PORT)

CERTIFICATE_FILE = os.getcwd() + '/CA/certs/02.pem'

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
sslSock = SSL.Connection(ctx, sock)
sslSock.connect(ADDRESS) #THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS

items = "this is a test Done"

sslSock.sendall(items)

sslSock.close()
```

Finally, the error:

```
File "SSLClient.py", line 19, in <module> sslSock.connect(ADDRESS)
File "<string>", line 1, in connect
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Any help would be appreciated. I get the feeling I'm missing something simple, but I am new to network programming.

`netstat -tpn` output while the server is running:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)

Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:59724     74.125.227.0:80         ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:49758     74.125.227.16:80        ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:39299     69.30.156.16:443        ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:44128     23.0.38.218:80          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:41272     64.34.119.101:80        ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:39420     69.30.156.26:443        ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:39418     69.30.156.26:443        ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:41218     64.34.119.101:80        ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:56224     198.183.6.22:22         ESTABLISHED 3156/ssh
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:54281     74.125.227.10:443       ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:46349     69.30.156.11:443        ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:54380     74.125.227.62:443       ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:42252     75.126.125.212:80       ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:39300     69.30.156.16:443        ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:53321     74.125.227.15:443       ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:60669     74.125.227.0:80         ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:54285     74.125.227.10:443       ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:37783     74.125.137.125:5222     ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:897       198.183.6.22:2049       ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:45040     69.171.248.16:443       ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:54286     74.125.227.10:443       ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:54284     74.125.227.10:443       ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:38499     74.125.227.21:443       ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:54157     173.194.33.47:443       ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:44312     70.84.101.150:6667      ESTABLISHED 5776/xchat
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:46074     69.30.156.32:80         ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:39298     69.30.156.16:443        ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:58444     74.125.227.16:443       ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:39056     198.183.6.100:993       ESTABLISHED 3180/thunderbird-bi
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:54283     74.125.227.10:443       ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:54910     173.194.64.116:80       ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:10050     198.183.6.231:34955     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:56503     72.247.172.20:80        ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:52454     173.194.64.95:443       ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:968       198.183.6.11:2049       ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:39419     69.30.156.26:443        ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:52088     74.125.227.0:443        ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:33184     198.183.6.1:6667        ESTABLISHED 5776/xchat
tcp        0      0 198.183.6.199:39417     69.30.156.26:443        ESTABLISHED 2128/google-chrome
```

Comment: For one, your port number is too high. Port numbers are from 0-65535.

Comment: Changed the port number to within the range and still get the error.

Comment: On which operating system are you, and what's the output of `netstat -tpn` there while the server runs? Do you have any firewall configured?

Comment: No firewall, the same socket calls work minus SSL. Working on 10.04 Ubuntu.

Comment: The netstat -tpn output has been added to the question

Comment: It did not print that very well at all :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

`SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer.__init__(self, address, handler)`

in your subclass, the ThreadingTCPServer will create a socket and do the bind/listen. After that line you do

```
self.socket = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(self.address_family, self.socket_type))
```

to create your SSL socket. This socket does not get bound though. What you need to do is call the super class' constructor differently:

`SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer.__init__(self, address, handler, bind_and_activate=False)`

Note the last argument. This will prevent the superclass from binding the socket that it creates. Then, after you create your socket, call `self.server_bind()` and `self.server_activate()` so that the socket you created is properly setup.

In summary, try changing your server to:

```
class SSLThreadingTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer):
    def __init__(self, address, handler):
        SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer.__init__(self, address, handler, bind_and_activate=False)

        ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)

        #ctx.use_privatekey_file(KEY_PATH)
        #ctx.use_certificate_file(CERTIFICATE_PATH)
        self.socket = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(self.address_family, self.socket_type))
        self.server_bind()
        self.server_activate()


        print "Serving:", address[0], "on port:", address[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up the connection refused problem. Now I just can't complete the handshake. Progress!

Comment: Did not work for me on `Debian 4.7.2-5 x64`. Call to `netstat -tpn` didn't show anything of interest